# How can i parse php functions from JSON string variable?

Tags: php, json, php-parser

I want to extract and run PHP functions from a JSON string variable.
my string variable is something like this :

```
$str = '"field_table_id": {
    "element_name": "select",
    "title": "some_title",
    "attributes": {
        "id": "field_table_id"
    },
    "options": {
        "values" : "@php_function ['function1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] @end_php",
        "titles" : "@php_function ['function1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] @end_php"
    }
}';
```

how can I do this?

Comment: lol, you just asked the question and answered it at almost same time

Comment: This seems like you are trying to create a template, but it seems fairly inflexible.  Yes you can call functions - but it looks like the parameters lack any real flexibility.

Comment: please let me know your suggestion about the parameters.

Comment: And why would you do this over `"<h4><?php function1('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'); ?></h4>"` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes we can use this too but with my method we can create our own HTML template.

Comment: @Haridarshan Yes, that's a Stack Overflow feature which comes in handy when you have some knowledge you want what to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ask this question I think the following answer is right but I found a better solution now.

<s>I write a simple function for this. you can use this function in your codes.</s>

```
function php_function_parser( $string ) {
    $valid_functions = array( 'function1', 'function2' );
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/@php_function(.*?)@end_php/m',
        function ($matches) {
            $usr_function = $matches[1];
            eval("\$usr_function = $usr_function;");
            if ( is_array($usr_function) ) {
                if ( in_array($usr_function[0], $valid_functions) ) {
                    $fnc_name = $usr_function[0];
                    array_shift($usr_function);
                    if ( is_array($usr_function) ) {
                        return call_user_func_array( $fnc_name, $usr_function );
                    } else {
                        return call_user_func( $fnc_name, $usr_function );
                    }
                } else {
                    return 'invalid or forbidden php function use';
                }
            }
        },
        $string
    );
    return $string;
}
```

usage:

```
$str = "<h4>@php_function ['function1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'] @end_php</h4>";
echo php_function_parser($str);
```

My new solution is :
In JSON syntax curly braces hold objects and square brackets hold arrays suppose I change the JSON to the following string :

```
{
    "field_table_id": {
        "element_name": "select",
        "title": "programming lanquages",
        "attributes": "json_object('element_attrs')",
        "options": {
            "values" : "json_array('options_values')"
        }
    }
}
```

I want replace

```
json_object('element_attrs')
```

with a PHP array like this as JSON object:

```
array('id' => 'select1', 'value' => 'php', 'style' => 'width:30%')
```

and

```
json_array('options_values')
```

with this PHP array as JSON array:

```
array('php', 'html', 'js', 'jquery')
```

the following PHP function to this for us

```
function readOurJson( string $json_path, array $replaces = array() ) {
    if ( is_file($json_path) ) {
        $json_string = file_get_contents( $json_path );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $json_string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\"(json_array|json_object)\(\'([a-zA-Z]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*)\'\)\"/m',
        function ($matches) use ($replaces) {
            if ( ! empty($matches) ) {
                $key = $matches[2];
                switch ( $matches[1] ) {
                    case 'json_array' :
                        if ( isset($replaces[$key]) ) {
                            if ( is_array($replaces[$key]) ) {
                                $json_array = '"' . implode( '","', $replaces[$key] ) . '"';
                                return "[$json_array]";
                            }
                        }
                    case 'json_object' :
                        if ( isset($replaces[$key]) ) {
                            if ( is_array($replaces[$key]) ) {
                                $json_object = json_encode($replaces[$key]);
                                return $json_object;
                            }
                        }
                }
                return $matches[0];
            }
        },
        $json_string
    );
    return json_decode($json_string);
}
```

usage:

```
$replaces = array(
    'element_attrs' => array('id' => 'select1', 'value' => 1, 'style' => 'width:30%'),
    'options_values' => array('php', 'html', 'js', 'jquery')
);
$array = readOurJson( $json_path, $replaces);
var_dump($array);
```

[Test Code on PHP Sandbox](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/dfd73)
Let me know if you have any suggestions or corrections.

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: valid_functions`

Comment: i have some html template and i use this function to extract and replace php function used in html template.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a theme and template system in PHP, but for what you show, just changing PHP syntax slightly to change it back again is not beneficial.  However, if you are open to using double-quotes instead `["function1", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`then you can treat it as JSON:

```
preg_match('/@php_function(.*)@end_php/', $str, $args);
$args = json_decode($args[1]);
$func = array_shift($args);

if(function_exists($func)) {
    $func(...$args);
} else {
    echo "$func not defined";
}
```

To stay with the single-quotes (it may break if you have a mix):

```
$args = json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $args[1]));
```

Or evaluate it as PHP:

```
eval("\$args = {$args[1]};");
```

Just add `in_array($func, $valid_functions)` check if needed.

Comment: thanks a lot, simple and effective answer.I think you must switch from preg_match to preg_match_all function to extract all match.

Comment: Yes, this is just an example of shorter ways.